# Bitwise Operation !x and x==0

Tags: c, xc8

I just want to ask a question.

Is `!x` the same as `x==0` ?

I'm using these to test a condition (an interrupt), in this case `x` is only a single bit.
Sample of the code where I'm using it:

```
if(PIR1bits.SSPIF & !SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT)
{
      // some operation
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `==`

Answer (score 4):

Why not do a simple table ?

```
x  !x  x==0
0   1   1
1   0   0
```

So the evaluation of `if(!x)` or `if(x==0)` should be the same in your case.

**edit**
Just to precise that in your code the `&` operator refers to the bitwise AND operator so your condition can only be true if `PIR1bits.SSPIF=1` and `SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT=0`

Answer (score 0):

As noted by coincoin, you probably want your code to read

```
if(PIR1bits.SSPIF && !SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT) {...}
```

so that you are using a logical 'and' rather than a bitwise 'and'. Bitwise operators (&, |, ^, ~) are usually used to implement masks where you want to test, set, or clear bits within a byte or word. If you use them in if statements, you risk weird behaviour that can be difficult to debug.

You can do things like

```
if (i & 0x80) {...}
```

to test if bit 15 is set, or something like

```
uint16_t a, b;
a = b & 0xfff0;
```

to clear the lower nibble of b and assign this to a.